# Is “I go cycling a bike. “ correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> I go cycling a bike in a park.

Is the above sentence correct?

Comment: **to cycle** in the meaning "ride a bike" is *intransitive*. It does not take a direct object.   *I like to cycle where cars are not allowed.*

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately that is not common usage. Here are some suggested alternatives:

"I am riding a bike in a park." The most common verb for cycling is "to ride". This would be the most common usage in US English.

"I am cycling in a park." Generally, you wouldn't say "cycling a bike" as that is redundant - cycling only happens on a bicycle. In US English, this would be slightly more formal than 'riding a bike'.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound right.

I would say

> I go cycling in a park.

If you do want to use bike in your sentence you can say riding a bike, not cycling a bike!

Answer (score 0):

No it **isn't correct** to say:

> "I go cycling a bike".

Cycling describes the action of riding a bike. It would be like saying:

> I hammer a hammer.

You don't; but you may say that you hammer a *nail*.

In British English we would say:

> I go cycling.

or

> I ride a bike.

or

> I go bike-riding

It's possible someone might say:

> I go cycling *on* my bike.

Now, that last option will sound a little tautological to many and so won't be often used. But you *can* cycle on a tricycle! So it isn't technically incorrect. Just as one might say "I go driving my car".